# can someone tell me what the error in this page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i get this error line on this php file . can someone locate where is the error ?

-------------You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1----------

i have this page for votes to users but if i vote in one user this vote goes to all users . how can i make this code when voting this vote goes only to its user .
          --

```
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "dbusername", "dbpassword") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("mydatabase") or die(mysql_error()); 

//We only run this code if the user has just clicked a voting link
 if ( $mode=="vote") 
 { 

 //If the user has already voted on the particular thing, we do not allow them to vote     again    
    //$cookie = "Mysite$id"; 
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) 
    { 
    Echo "Sorry You have already ranked that site <p>"; 
    } 

 //Otherwise, we set a cooking telling us they have now voted 
else 
    { 
    $month = 2592000 + time(); 
    setcookie('Mysite'.$id, 'Voted', $month); 

     //Then we update the voting information by adding 1 to the total votes     and adding their vote (1,2,3,etc) to the total rating 

 mysql_query ("UPDATE userads SET total = total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id =     $id"); 

    } 
 } 
  if ( $mode2=="vote") 
 { 

 //If the user has already voted on the particular thing, we do not allow them to vote     again    
    //$cookie = "Mysite$id"; 
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) 
    { 
    Echo "Sorry You have already ranked that site <p>"; 
    } 

 //Otherwise, we set a cooking telling us they have now voted 
else 
    { 
    $month = 2592000 + time(); 
    setcookie('Mysite'.$id, 'Voted', $month); 

     //Then we update the voting information by adding 1 to the total votes     and adding their vote (1,2,3,etc) to the total rating 

 mysql_query ("UPDATE userads SET total = total+$voted, nvotes = nvotes+1 WHERE id =     $id"); 

    } 
 }  

 //Puts SQL Data into an array
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userads WHERE id = $id ") or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Now we loop through all the data 
 while($ratings = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 

?>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 { 
<?php
echo '<div id="voting_14" class="voting voting_template_votess-up-down">';
echo "<strong class='positive_votes'>";
$current = $ratings[votes];
echo "<span>+" . round($current,0) . "</span>";
echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=1&id=".$ratings[id].">       <input class='vote_positive' type='submit'></a>";
echo '</strong>';

echo "<strong class='negative_votes'>";
$current2 = $ratings[nvotes]; 
echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode2=vote&voted=2&id=".$ratings[id].">      <input class='vote_negative' type='submit'></a>";
echo "<span>-". round($current2,0) ."</span>";
echo '</strong>';

echo '</div>';

 } 
 ---the end
```

i have sql table userads  with : id , name , username , total, votes , nvotes.

Comment: uhhhh, you are asking too much here.

Comment: Try adding a `error_reporting(E_ALL)` line at the top of this file. Also, why are you capitalizing `Echo` on some lines?

Comment: You posted this question yesterday (and seem to have deleted that one). how about cutting this code down to a useful EXAMPLE? we're not going to try and figure out what your wall of code is doing, which is necessary to try and figure out why it's not working.

Comment: If you indented this code neatly it would make it much easier for us to debug. However you really are asking a lot. Check your log files for errors first.

Comment: animous i writed echo but the same . get this error line You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: marc B , i didnt cut my code , its cutted by it self here

Comment: @goodmood I'm pretty sure you deleted an identical question some hours ago; it had an equal amount of good answers IIRC; what's gone wrong? Don't wait for people to give you the correct code (that seems to be the attitude, judging by your questions and comments), a good things of making mistakes is the ability to learn from them. If you keep asking people to do the work for you, you'll always be dependent from someone else's mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your code to following,

```
setcookie('Mysite'.$id, 'Voted', $month); // ERROR 1
```

and

```
 while($ratings = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{  // ERROR 2
?>
```

Comment: thanks for this code but i still get this error    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted your code in a file and ran:

```
php -l your_script.php
```

Yields:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in your_script.php on line 78
```

So, that last bracket `}` at the very end is causing a parse error. Either that or you didn't post the matching `if`/`while`/etc. in your post and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: what you mean by this  - /while/

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. Probably your configuration doesn't display errors and you get a blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes here:

```
  setcookie(Mysite.$id, Voted, $month);
```

It should be:

```
  setcookie('Mysite'.$id, 'Voted', $month);
```

Comment: i have corrected this error but still get error line  .....  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something is wrong with your query. You can check your SQL query with a simple:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM userads WHERE id = $id ";
echo $sql;
```

My first guess is, that `$id` is not set properly.

Comment: I'm confused; what do you mean by 'how'?

Comment: its only guess ,thats why i told you how is the real .

Comment: There's at least one more syntax error in your code: `$ratings[id]` should be `$ratings['id']`.